# 85/5000 Asynchronous equation in PHP: a variable depends on another that has not yet been declared

Tags: php

I have a sum in my code that needs the return of a function, but the return of this function depends that the sum is already ready, because it uses a parameter that is still going to be created, can you solve it?

It's a calculator made in excel and I'm programming, but excel is that way and it works, but when I went to the code I got caught up in that problem.

//See the code:

```
public function valorRenda($rendaMensal, $valorEntrada, $tempoMeses, $imovelTipo){
    $resultado = array();

    $resultado['tipoSimulacao'] = 'rendaCliente';

    $taxaMensal = $this->taxaPorTipo('rendaCliente', $imovelTipo, $rendaMensal) / 100;


    //Cálculo do valor da primeira parcela
    $primeiraParcela = $rendaMensal * 0.3;

    //Calcula valor máximo do financiamento
    $multiplicador = 0.5;

    $i = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 9999999999; $i++) {
      $amortizacao = ($i * $multiplicador) / $tempoMeses;
      $juros = (($i * $multiplicador) * ($taxaMensal));
      $valor = $amortizacao + $juros + $this->custoMensal($valorImovel,$valorEntrada);

      if ($valor >= $primeiraParcela) {
        $projecao = ($i * $multiplicador) + $valorEntrada;
        $valorImovel = ($projecao * $primeiraParcela / $valor);
        break;
      }
    }

    $financiamentoMaximo = round($valorImovel);
    $financiamentoMaximo = $this->formatoReal($financiamentoMaximo);
    $resultado['financiamentoMaximo'] = $financiamentoMaximo;
    $resultado['financiamentoMaximoFormatado'] = $this->formatoReal($financiamentoMaximo, false);

    //Calcula a primeira parcela
    $primeiraParcelaSemTaxas = $primeiraParcela - $this->custoMensal($valorImovel,$valorEntrada);
    $primeiraParcelaSemTaxas = round($primeiraParcelaSemTaxas, 2);
    $primeiraParcelaSemTaxas = $this->formatoReal($primeiraParcelaSemTaxas);
    $resultado['primeiraParcela'] = $primeiraParcelaSemTaxas;
    $resultado['primeiraParcelaFormatado'] = $this->formatoReal($primeiraParcelaSemTaxas, false);

    $primeiraParcelaTotal = $primeiraParcela;
    $primeiraParcelaTotal = round($primeiraParcelaTotal, 2);
    $primeiraParcelaTotal = $this->formatoReal($primeiraParcelaTotal);
    $resultado['primeiraParcelaTotal'] = $primeiraParcelaTotal;
    $resultado['primeiraParcelaTotalFormatado'] = $this->formatoReal($primeiraParcelaTotal, false);

    $valorUltimaParcela = ((($valorImovel - $valorEntrada) - ((($valorImovel - $valorEntrada) / $tempoMeses) * ($tempoMeses - 1))) + ((($valorImovel - $valorEntrada) - ((($valorImovel - $valorEntrada) / $tempoMeses) * ($tempoMeses - 1)))) * $taxaMensal) + $this->custoMensal($valorImovel,$valorEntrada);
    $ultimaParcelaSemTaxas = $valorUltimaParcela - $this->custoMensal($valorImovel,$valorEntrada);
    $ultimaParcelaSemTaxas = round($ultimaParcelaSemTaxas, 2);
    $ultimaParcelaSemTaxas = $this->formatoReal($ultimaParcelaSemTaxas);
    $resultado['ultimaParcela'] = $ultimaParcelaSemTaxas;
    $resultado['ultimaParcelaFormatado'] = $this->formatoReal($ultimaParcelaSemTaxas, false);

    $primeiraParcelaTotal = $valorUltimaParcela;
    $primeiraParcelaTotal = round($primeiraParcelaTotal, 2);
    $primeiraParcelaTotal = $this->formatoReal($primeiraParcelaTotal);
    $resultado['ultimaParcelaTotal'] = $primeiraParcelaTotal;
    $resultado['ultimaParcelaTotalFormatado'] = $this->formatoReal($primeiraParcelaTotal, false);

    $resultado['taxa'] = number_format(round(($taxaMensal * 100), 2), 2);


    $resultado['periodo'] = $tempoMeses;

    $this->incluiCustoMensal($resultado);

    return $resultado;
  }
```

//The function:

```
private function custoMensal($valorImovel, $entradaImovel)
  {`enter code here`
    $taxa_dfi = ($this->dfi / 100) * $valorImovel;
    $taxa_mip = ($this->mip / 100) * ($valorImovel- $entradaImovel);
    return $taxa_dfi +  $taxa_mip + $this->tac;
  }
```

Where is the problem:

```
   $valor = $amortizacao + $juros + $this->custoMensal($valorImovel,$valorEntrada);
```

In this line I need to pass $valorImovelto the function custoMensal(), what happens is that the variable $valorImovel has not yet been created because it depends on the variable $valor.

Comment: That is some strange math; I could be wrong, but it would seem to me that if the values depend on each other, your equation has multiple solutions. That sounds like a serious problem...

Comment: Looks like at least `$valorImovel` should have an initial value (0 maybe? I have no idea). I don't know what is going on in the methods you call, neither do I know what problem you are solving with this code, so I can't give you proper advice. Also: Try to make it a habbit to write code in English. I'm Dutch, but all the code I write is in English.

Comment: Exactly @jeroen